# VisualStudio: Should one use a separate Resource-Files-Project for Resource-Files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, embedded-resource, multilingual

We are starting to develop a new asp.net mvc 5 application that should be multilingual.

I found a very nice [tutorial](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) how to get this working. The only thing I wonder about this tutorial is, that the author suggests to create a separate project inside the solution for the resources.

Now my question: Is this recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually create a folder called `Resources` inside my MVC project.  Although if you wish to reference your resources from other projects, you may wish to create them inside a separate project.

I then sub-folder based on my controller names and change the 'Custom Tool' property to 'PublicResXFileCodeGenerator'.

When I use the resource strings in my *Views*, it looks like:

```
<title>@Resources.Home.Index.PageTitle</title>
```

Personally, I prefer to use a folder rather than a project, as this forces me to not generate UI strings in my application layers and forces me to find better ways to solve problems where I might end up generating strings in my business logic that might end up in the UI.

Comment: sorry, I corrected it. I ment separate project inside the solution.

Answer (score 2):

We have resource files in projects where they are most relevant.

We have a component that handles the translation of resources on different levels 
( also for Winforms and WPF...) 
and we group resource files according to functional importance,
bussiness level messages in a project for the Bussiness layer,
a project for common translations used by our standard code.

A .NET ResourceManager can handle one resource file, so our manager keeps a list of ResourceManagers.

At runtime you just try them all ( or work with logical category names to speed up the lookup)...